# Sitemap XML line breaks: /n OR /r/n

Tags: xml, sitemap, line-breaks, xml-formatting

I'm currently writing a function to generate a dynamic site map for my web app.

And I'm using template strings with backticks to build them, like:

```
let sitemapXML = `
  <urlset>
    <url>
      <loc>https://www.myproject.net/blog</loc>
      <lastmod>${mostRecent.toISOString().slice(0,19) + '+00:00'}</lastmod>
      <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
      <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>
  </urlset>
`;
```

While this looks great on code, it messes with the XML syntax, since there's an empty line as the first line, and it also makes my XML response "ugly", with a bunch of extra spaces. So I'm thinking about doing:

```
// REMOVE ALL SPACES AND LINE BREAKS TO GET A SINGLE LINE STRING
sitemapXML = sitemapXML.replace(/" "/gm, "").replace(/\n/gm, "");
```

And use an `xml-formatter` to make it "pretty".

**QUESTION**

[image]

This [xml-formatter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-formatter) lets you choose your line break characters. What should I choose? `\n` or `\r\n`? Is there a difference between the two or it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XML parser converts any `\r\n` to `\n` automatically, so you might as well generate `\n` to save it unnecessary work.

Getting rid of all spaces seems questionable. For example it will change `<a id="n"/>` to `<aid="n"/>` which is not well-formed XML.

Comment: Thanks! Can I send it all as one line of string? While keeping the necessary spaces, like you mentioned, of course.

Comment: Yes, the XML can all be on one line. Technically whitespace between tags is significant, but in practice this only applies to document-like XML where you get structures like `<p>A <i>nice</i> <b>mess</b></p>`.